# If i use the php function mysql_insert_id(), does the server need to make another connection to the database?

Tags: php, mysql

If i use the php function mysql_insert_id($link), does the server need to make another trip to the database?

(You can assume the $link exists)

Comment: You mean another roundtrip? Hopefully you don't mean a new connection just to do this, as if you have an open connection, just use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes the database will be queried again to retrieve the last insert id.

Comment: so how do we generally avoid this problem? i don't like additional round trips to the database from the web server

Comment: if you need the value i dont think you can get around this. If you need it for another query mysql has a function LAST_INSERT_ID() that you can use to assign it to value in your query rather than looking it up before

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php):

> The MySQL connection. If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed. If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() was called with no arguments. If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING level error is generated.

So, the answer is: it depends.

Comment: i mean the $link exists. i mean does the web server need to take another trip to the database?

Comment: the database will be queried, but with an existent link. your `$link`.

Comment: It will depend on the requests that your database receives. you may want to avoid using it without needs, but in most of the situations, you will face it. You probably would want to do some tests. Probably it will not overhead your database, if it's working fine so far.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from [the documentation topic](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php), it does not do that, because it can take an optional mysql connection object for a parameter (if it's not provided, the last used one will be used).

Comment: i mean does the web server need to take another trip to the database?

Comment: @Pacerier of course it does. How can it interogate the database without communicating with it?

Comment: i'd thought the results of the last inserted id may have been cached already?